# Quickest way to roll back SQL data Was: Best way to develop a data-mangling stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Edit: OK I asked the wrong question here.

I'm going to be coding a stored proc that affects a lot of data, so I need to know the quickest, easiest way to roll back the data to the original state after I run a test.

---

Old question:
I have a development database holding live data. This needs to be obfuscated for privacy, particularly company names and contact details.

To throw a spanner in the works the company NAME is the primary key. (.... yes, i know. legacy code. hooray.)

Now, I need to obfuscate the company name (say, change each to "Company 001" etc.) while preserving referential integrity with dozens of tables linked by this value. During my testing I'm going to mangle a lot of data, and then need to roll back to the original state after testing, probably many times before i get the procedure correct.

So the process will be:

- Mangle company data
- test within the application to ensure linked data displays correctly
- roll back data for bugfixes
  repeat

My initial thought is to simply back up and restore after each test. But this seems time consuming. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Test database with dummy data if that is available. Blow it away and repopulate with more random dummy data. If you already have fixtures for this then you are most of the way there. If you don't this is a good way to get started writing them.

Other than that backup and restore is probably your best bet.

Comment: backup and restore ended up being the best option

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing data tests of some kind, please considering using a test database or a playground database for this...

If that is not possible... The code below will rollback all the data changes...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
--do my tests
ROLLBACK
```

**EDIT**
You could also add some code into your application that will perform the tests and then restore a backup after your test is complete.

Comment: definitely will be using a test DB, that doesn't change the need to roll back

transactions aren't going to help unfortunately because I have to test the application after the proc has run

Answer (score 1):

IMHO mangling data inside your database is going to do little more than muck up your database. If prying eyes have gained access to your database I fear you have bigger problems on your hands at worst and at best they'll figure out how to undo the mangling. They did, hypothetically after all, just gain access to your database. Reversing some obfuscation will be the easy part.

Comment: +1 cause even though it doesn't answer his direct question it's the right answer.

Comment: you're going to love this - the prying eyes they're attempting to protect the data from are the developers... (yes, Me.)

it's hilariously stupid but there's no sidestepping this one with logic/reason/intelligent conversation, so i just have to get it done.

Comment: Ugh. That's always frustrating. In that case I would suggest the simplest approach possible. If the people forcing you to do this aren't that technically inclined I'd do something like a circular letter shift for some arbitrary distance IE (a -> c, b -> d , z -> b etc) Should be enough to satisfy them but not cause you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Options I've discovered so far:

Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.1 for MS SQL 2005

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en

(one hyperlink limit)

Answer (score 0):

If the database has referential integrity enabled via foreign key constraints that aren't setup to auto update on change then the commit should fail.

You could update the constraints to auto change on update so when you update the parent record, the child records are then updated automatically.

Comment: great in theory but almost never true in practice.

Comment: That's why the "If" is in there.